# Avoid unicity constraint on sub object in spring with jpa and hibernate in oracle datablase

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

After all sorry for my bad english.

Actually i use jpa and hibernate on my spring boot application.

I save an entity who have a list of other entity in one to many.

Example:

```
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "T_FOO")
@Entity
class Foo{
private string id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Singular
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
@Table(name = "T_BAR", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"FOO_ID", "TYPE"}))
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
class Bar {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Foo foo;
    private String  type;
}
```

On my application i receive a lot of data similar who are deduplicated. So i receive sometimes the same contact in the same contact, and this integration trigger the unique constraint of a bar.

My question is, in the following case:

```
Foo{
    bars: {
          bar 1 => unique constraint, 
          bar 2, 
          bar 3
}
```

It's possible to tell to hibernate to bypass the save of the bar 1 beacause he already exist? and just save the foo, the bar 2 and the bar 3?

Thank you in advance for your answers

EDIT:
It's save with a Transationnal Annotation who came from import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

```
@Transactional 
public void updateFooFromHistory(String fooId) {    
     fooRepository.findById(fooId).ifPresent(foo -> { 
         Set<FooHistory> fooHistorics = getFooHistoricsFromFoo(foo); 
         updateFooFromHistoryServices.forEach(updateFooFromHistoryService                  -> 
             updateFooFromHistoryService.updateFooFromHistory(foo, fooHistorics)); 
        }); 
}
```

Comment: how do you save it?

Comment: With a save method of a repository:

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {
}

Comment: So you simply have to catch the exception.

Comment: You mean catch the exception, update the list by the existing list in the db?

Comment: If you save row by row one row with throw a duplicate key exception and then you can ignore this

Comment: Sorry i have do a misstake, i have confonding with a another application, here we save with a tansationnal annotation from import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: ```
 @Transactional
    public void updateFooFromHistory(String fooId) {
        fooRepository.findById(fooId).ifPresent(foo -> {
            Set<FooHistory> fooHistorics = getFooHistoricsFromFoo(foo);
            updateFooFromHistoryServices.forEach(updateFooFromHistoryService -> updateFooFromHistoryService.updateFooFromHistory(foo, fooHistorics));
        });
    }
```

The elements on the foreach doesnt save, he just modify element into Foo object

Comment: And on witch lane do you get the exectpion?

Comment: i dont have line, it's when method is finished

Comment: Ah sure! You should call saveAndFlush instead of save then you will get the constraint violiation exception

Comment: @Kawarz, did you think in a easiest option. call from JPA a procedure to make the update, thereby the procedure can handled any exception, in this case as is unique constraint violated, it should include `val_dup_on_index` . In this case, your JPA must run a procedure, not an update

Comment: @SimonMartinelli okay i will try the next week for this parameters, thanks!

Comment: @RobertoHernandez thanks for your answer, i will look for it to. My subject matter skills are meager, so I would see to be helped on this point